# Replacement for ImageMenuItem

Tags: c#, gtk3, gtk#

Since `ImageMenuItem` is deprecated in GTK3 I'm looking for a replacement. I tried to take a simple `MenuItem` instead and packed an `Image` and an `AccelLabel` into it. (See example below.) Although this is working on the whole there are still two issues:

1. The accelerator key is not displayed in the menu item.
2. There's a big margin left to the icon.

In the following example the `File|Open` item was created with the deprecated `ImageMenuItem` whereas the `File|New` item was my attempt to get the same result with `MenuItem`.

What am I missing to make `MenuItem` look like `ImageMenuItem`?

```
class Program {

    public static void Main ()
    {
        Gtk.Application.Init();

        var win = new Gtk.Window("test");
        var mb = new Gtk.MenuBar();

        var accels = new Gtk.AccelGroup();
        win.AddAccelGroup(accels);

        var fileMenu = new Gtk.MenuItem("File");
        mb.Add(fileMenu);
        var fileSubmenu = new Gtk.Menu();
        fileMenu.Submenu = fileSubmenu;

        //
        // File | New
        //
        var fileNew = new Gtk.MenuItem();
        fileSubmenu.Add(fileNew);
        fileNew.AddAccelerator(
            "activate", accels,
            new Gtk.AccelKey(Gdk.Key.n, Gdk.ModifierType.ControlMask, Gtk.AccelFlags.Visible));
        fileNew.Activated += (s,e) => System.Console.WriteLine("New ...");

        var fileNewIcon = new Gtk.Image();
        fileNewIcon.SetFromIconName("document-new", Gtk.IconSize.Menu);
        var fileNewLabel = new Gtk.AccelLabel("New");
        fileNewLabel.AccelWidget = fileNew;
        var hbox = new Gtk.HBox(false, 4);
        hbox.PackStart(fileNewIcon, false, false, 0);
        hbox.PackStart(fileNewLabel, false, false, 0);
        fileNew.Add(hbox);

        //
        // File | Open
        //
        var fileOpen = new Gtk.ImageMenuItem("Open", accels);
        var fileOpenIcon = new Gtk.Image();
        fileOpenIcon.SetFromIconName("document-open", Gtk.IconSize.Menu);
        fileOpen.Image = fileOpenIcon;
        fileOpen.AddAccelerator(
            "activate", accels,
            new Gtk.AccelKey(Gdk.Key.o, Gdk.ModifierType.ControlMask, Gtk.AccelFlags.Visible));
        fileOpen.Activated += (s,e) => System.Console.WriteLine("Open ...");
        fileSubmenu.Add(fileOpen);

        win.Add(mb);
        win.ShowAll();
        win.DeleteEvent += (s,e) => Gtk.Application.Quit();

        Gtk.Application.Run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using raw gtk calls: (just translate into the c# binding)

In order to make the accelerator visible you have to call:

```
gtk_label_set_xalign (fileNewLabel, 0.0);
```

EDIT: You also use PackStart twice when it should be:

```
gtk_container_add(hbox, fileNewIcon);
gtk_box_pack_end(hbox, fileNewLabel, true, true, 0);
```

The space to the left of the menu item is allocated for check boxes and can be disabled with:

```
gtk_menu_set_reserve_toggle_size (fileMenu , false);
```

However that only works if your menu does not have a GtkCheckMenuItem in it, since the deprecated GtkImageMenuItem had a hack in it to use the pre-reserved toggle size. I could not find a way to get a similar result to the original hack, which btw. was annotadet by the gtk team with:

```
/* Man this is lame hardcoding action, but I can't
 * come up with a solution that's really better.
 */
```

Comment: Ok, `fileSubmenu.ReserveToggleSize = false;` is working. But the accelerator (which would be `fileNewLabel.Xalign = 0.0f;`) is not shown...

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you added the items to the hboy differently, fixed it.

Comment: Hmm... doesn't work. I'm afraid I do not understand what the packing of the box has to do with the visibility of the accelerator key.

Comment: Accelerator keys are very allignment and packing sensitive and disappear if not in the correct position, no idea why. (Here's my code if it helps: https://pastebin.com/kSbW78uZ)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while dealing with deprecated calls in Gtkmm 3.24. Here is the function I came up with which works for me (note: error handling has been removed to only show the relevent code):

```cpp
// Icon names can be found here:
//
//    https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/0.8/ar01s04.html
//
// If no icon name is specified, the menu item will only show a text label. This is
// temporary because in Gtkmm4, `Gtk::MenuItem`s are deprecated. The "popover" technology
// should be used instead.
Gtk::MenuItem* MakeMenuItem(const std::string& p_label, const std::string& p_iconName = {})
{ 
    Gtk::Image* menuItemImageLabel = nullptr;
    if(!p_iconName.empty())
    {
        menuItemImageLabel = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Image(p_iconName, Gtk::BuiltinIconSize::ICON_SIZE_MENU));
    }
    else
    {
        // If no icon name is specified, we use an "empty" icon, to make sure all
        // menu string labels are aligned, like before:
        const Gtk::IconSize iconSize = Gtk::BuiltinIconSize::ICON_SIZE_MENU;
        int width, height;
        Gtk::IconSize::lookup(iconSize, width, height);
        const auto iconSurface = Cairo::ImageSurface::create(Cairo::Format::FORMAT_ARGB32, width, height);
        menuItemImageLabel = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Image(iconSurface));
    }

    Gtk::AccelLabel* menuItemAccelLabel = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::AccelLabel(p_label));
    menuItemAccelLabel->set_xalign(0.0);

    Gtk::Box* menuItemLabelLayout = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Box());
    menuItemLabelLayout->set_spacing(5);
    menuItemLabelLayout->pack_start(*menuItemImageLabel, false, false);
    menuItemLabelLayout->pack_start(*menuItemAccelLabel, true, true);
    
    Gtk::MenuItem* menuItem = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::MenuItem(*menuItemLabelLayout));
    menuItemAccelLabel->set_accel_widget(*menuItem);

    return menuItem;
}
```

which can be used like so:

```cpp
m_undoMenuItem = MakeMenuItem("Undo", "edit-undo");
```

Showing accelerator keys in the menu seems to be very sensible to the way things are packed and aligned, just like Kyto suggested. Here is a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image: Non deprecated menu]

The free space on the left is the price to pay to keep the "menu item" technology. I think one can remove it by using some CSS tricks, but I personally do not care.